# Absolute path of bridging header in compiled SDK header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, absolute-path, bridging-header

I am creating a SDK in Swift which imports an Objective C SDK.Hence I am using a bridging header for the same.
When I successfully compile the Swift SDK, the swift header file which is generated imports absolute path of the bridging header like

```
#import "/User/myName/Development/ProjectFolder/../BridgingHeader.h"
```

When I use this SDK in my another Swift project, it imports the framework and everything works fine.
On the other hand when I import the framework in Objective C file, it gives me error for the absolute path which was generated for bridging header as file not found.

What makes it work in Swift but not in Objective C?

Comment: I have the same problem but it is regarding build for device vs. build for simulator - on Xcode 9 the build works when I delete that line from the header manually, but on Xcode 10 it crashes in simulator build of the app which uses the sdk. How did you solve it? How can I get rid of that line right way?